# Behaviour of is_callable on '/'

Tags: php

My colleague and I have encountered some rather odd behavour. Our environments are Ubuntu 11.10, PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch, and Windows 7 PHP 5.3.5.

On our machines, the following code runs as one would expect:

```
<?php
function t() { }
var_dump(is_callable('/'));
```

With the output:

```
bool(false)
```

On one of our servers, CentOS release 5.7 (Final), PHP 5.3.8, the same code produces:

```
bool(true)
```

Without the `t()` function, `is_callable` performs as expected. Note that `is_function` behaves the same as `is_callable` in these tests.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

**Edit**:

It seems to only happen when a function named `t` is present, anything else, like `b`, `c` etc, and the output is as expected.

**Edit - testing with more characters**:

```
<?php
function t() { }
foreach(str_split('/abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ!@#$%^&*()-_+=`~;:[]{}\\|\'"?.>,<') as $character) {
    if (is_callable($character)) var_dump($character, is_callable($character));
}
```

Outputs the following on the server:

```
string(1) "/"
bool(true)
string(1) "t"
bool(true)
string(1) "T"
bool(true)
string(1) "_" // gettext
bool(true)
string(1) ":" // With the t() function undefined, this remains callable on the server
bool(true)
```

On our environments, the output is as expected:

```
string(1) "t"
bool(true)
string(1) "T"
bool(true)
```

**Edit - more information on cbuckley's comment**:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
function t() { }
$v = '/'; $v();
```

Produces output: `Call to undefined function /()`

Comment: That's really bizarre. Is it only for `'/'`?

Comment: @Hamish I've updated my question with code testing `is_callable` on more characters

Comment: What happens when you do `$v = '/'; $v();`?

Comment: @cbuckley: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function /()`

Comment: PHP, you continue to baffle me. http://bugs.php.net :-)

Comment: More testing: try `is_callable('/', false, $realName); var_dump($realName);`

Comment: Try to compare the  loaded extension on both servers.

Comment: Because that can happen because of apc, eaccelerator or other accelerator extension.

Comment: @meze This is a good point, I will look into this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around you could try this:

```
$name = '/';
$actual = null;
if (is_callable($name, false, $actual) && $name === $actual) {
    // Method is actually callable
}
```